# Is there any way to not use in-memory authentication? @PreAuthorize, @Secured, @RoleAllowed don't work

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

Questions: 1.How to link Authority to annotations?
Intent is to use current annotations to lock some APIs: @RoleAllowed("ROLE_VIEWER","ROLE_EDITOR"),@Secured({ "ROLE_VIEWER", "ROLE_EDITOR" }),@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')").
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true,securedEnabled=true,jsr250Enabled=true) is used already. DB is shown below. Firebase is used to generate/authenticate.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (
    ID VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    LOGIN VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    STATUS SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT UC_USER_LOGIN UNIQUE (LOGIN));
    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AUTHORITY (
    ID VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT UC_AUTHORITY_NAME UNIQUE (NAME));
    
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_AUTHORITY (
    ID VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_ID VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL REFERENCES USER (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    AUTHORITY_ID VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL REFERENCES AUTHORITY (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Can you describe in details what does it mean `don't work`? What's your web security config?